# Trouble with box-shadows not going over other elements

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm not sure why but my nav bar's shadow isn't going over the other elements? I'm using Skeleton Framework.

http://jades-world.com/schoolassign

If anyone could help me out I would appreciate it a whole lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add:

```
position:relative;
```

to the nav element.